# IDE features in NetBeans platform application

Tags: netbeans, editor, netbeans-platform

I am developing application based on the NetBeans platform. I use Maven to build it and I need to provide IDE features in my app (text editing, syntax highliting for XML files and so on).

Which libraries do I need to declare as dependencies to be able to provide the editor support? And what about XML syntax highliting (or full XML files support)? I am kinda lost in those dozens of JARs. Is there any way to include whole NB cluster? (To make sure everyone gets it, once again, I use Maven.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [NetBeans API index](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/index.html) in the content section there is a short description about what each API provides. At a guess I think you're wanting to use the [Editor Module](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/index.html) and maybe the [XML API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-api-xml/overview-summary.html)

I *think* that if you include the following dependency you will get the entire NetBeans (This is not something that I've tried) IDE as a dependecy

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.cluster</groupId>
        <artifactId>ide</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE70</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```